# Highcharts multiple series and axes types overlapping

Tags: highcharts, overlap, overlapping, series, axes

I have a problem with a highcharts graph, regarding overlapping of multiple axes.
There are 2 types of series, one type column and one type line. I want the line type to be always above the others and never intersect them.

You may see my problem here:
http://jsfiddle.net/99tC7/

Anticipated thank you for any help provided.

```
$('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Title',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [ "5.11.13", "6.11.13", "7.11.13", "8.11.13", "9.11.13"],
            labels: {
                rotation: 270
            }
        },
        yAxis: [{
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }],
            title:{
                text: "Number 1"
            },
        },
        {
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }],
            title:{
                text: "Number 2"
            },
            opposite: true,
            max:50,
            minPadding:5,
        }],
        legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter: function() {
                            return this.y +'%';
                    }
                }
            },
            column: {                    
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter: function() {
                            return this.y;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'L1',
            type: 'column',
            color: '#FF0000',
            yAxis: 0,
            data: [1, 5, 9, 10, 12]
            },
            {
            name: 'L2',
            type: 'column',
            color: '#00FF00',
            yAxis: 0,
            data: [16, 16, 106, 12, 11]
            },
            {
            name: 'L3',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [38, 24, 37, 29, 37]
            }
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set correct `min/max` values in both yAxis like here http://jsfiddle.net/99tC7/1/

Comment: well, the percent series has values in [0,100], but the columns do not have a max range, only min which is 0. Not a solution.

Comment: Why not determining the max value from the bigger value of your set and then multiplying this value. As example, if you have a set of 10 values and the bigger is 5000. Take this value X2 = 10000 and assign this value to the max property.